# Divergence, absolute or conditional convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (3n + \cos(n))^{-n}$$
Is this series either divergent, absolutely convergent, or conditionally convergent?

I've attempted to just start with one type of divergence/convergence (or lack thereof), but didn't get far on this specific question and, generally, find these types of questions very time-consuming (is there a standard go-to method? I usually work on divergence or absolute convergence first)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: For any $n\geq 2$, $$0\leq (3n+\cos n)^{-n}\leq (3n-1)^{-n} \leq \frac{1}{(3n-1)^2}\leq\frac{1}{n^2}.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Just out of curiosity, why didn't you post this as an answer?

Comment: @SuH: it feels like stealing from kids :D

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio You mean person ;)